# Printing char of a file with fgetc() ending with a "?" symbol

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the chars (with fgetc) in a file one by a one with a while loop.

I'm using the latest Atom editor to write the code, and I compile with the [GPP Compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler), by pressing F5 and the output is displayed in the xterm terminal.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  FILE* file = NULL;
  file = fopen("text.txt", "r+");
  int letter = 0;

  if (file != NULL)
  {
    while(letter != EOF)
    {
      letter = fgetc(file);
      printf("%c", letter);
    }
```

I expected the output to be the text in my file, which it is, but at the end there's a question mark symbol.
What I understood after doing some research is that my fgetc function reads the EOF like a normal character and prints it, resulting in a question mark symbol at the end.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... ending with a “?” symbol

doing

> ```
> while(letter != EOF)
> {
>   letter = fgetc(file);
>   printf("%c", letter);
> }
> ```

you print *letter* before to check if it is EOF, so you (try to) print EOF which is not a character, producing the unexpected output

Example of a valid code :

```
while ((letter = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
  putchar(letter); /* or printf("%c", letter); if you prefer */
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been having the same issue and I found out that the return type for fgetc is an integer and it may be returning -1.